# Zend Framework 3 access_filter

Tags: php, zend-framework

Something unusual is happening with my access filtering l have the following:

```
'access_filter' => [
            'options'=>['mode'=>'restrictive'],
            Controller\IndexController::class => [
                    ['actions' => ['index','signup','login'], 'allow' => '*'],
                    ['actions' => ['registration','search'], 'allow' => '@']
            ],

            'controllers' => [
            Controller\VehicleController::class => [
                // Give access to "index", "add", "edit", "view", "changePassword" actions to authorized users only.
                    ['actions' => ['results','index'], 'allow' => '@']
            ],
            Controller\AuthController::class => [
                // Allow anyone to visit "index" and "about" actions
                ['actions' => ['login','logout'], 'allow' => '*'],
            ],
            Controller\IndexController::class => [
                    ['actions' => ['index','signup'], 'allow' => '*'],
                    ['actions' => ['registration','search'], 'allow' => '@']
            ],
        ],
               ],
```

In Module.php

```
    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        // Get controller and action to which the HTTP request was dispatched.
        $controller = $event->getTarget();
        $controllerName = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('controller', null);
        $actionName = $event->getRouteMatch()->getParam('action', null);

        // Convert dash-style action name to camel-case.
        $actionName = str_replace('-', '', lcfirst(ucwords($actionName, '-')));

        // Get the instance of AuthManager service.
        $authManager = $event->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get(AuthManager::class);

        // Execute the access filter on every controller except
        // (to avoid infinite redirect).
        if (($controllerName!=SignupController::class && $controllerName!=AuthController::class) &&
            !$authManager->filterAccess($controllerName, $actionName)) {

            // Remember the URL of the page the user tried to access. We will
            // redirect the user to that URL after successful login.
            $uri = $event->getApplication()->getRequest()->getUri();
            // Make the URL relative (remove scheme, user info, host name and port)
            // to avoid redirecting to other domain by a malicious user.
            $uri->setScheme(null)
                ->setHost(null)
                ->setPort(null)
                ->setUserInfo(null);
            $redirectUrl = $uri->toString();

            // Redirect the user to the "Login" page.
           return $controller->redirect()->toRoute('login', [], 
                   ['query'=>['redirectUrl'=>$redirectUrl]]);
        }
    }
```

In Auth Manager:

```
/**
         * Authentication service.
         * @var \Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService
         */
        private $authService;

        /**
         * Session manager.
         * @var Zend\Session\SessionManager
         */
        private $sessionManager;

        /**
         * Contents of the 'access_filter' config key.
         * @var array 
         */
        private $config;

        /**
         * Constructs the service.
         */
        public function __construct($authService, $sessionManager, $config) 
        {
            $this->authService = $authService;
            $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
            $this->config = $config;
        }   

        /**
     * Performs user logout.
     */
    public function logout()
    {
       /**
     * Performs a login attempt. If $rememberMe argument is true, it forces the session
     * to last for one month (otherwise the session expires on one hour).
     */

        // Allow to log out only when user is logged in.
        if ($this->authService->getIdentity()==null) {
            //throw new \Exception('The user is not logged in');
        }

        // Remove identity from session.
        $this->authService->clearIdentity();               
    }

    public function login($email, $password, $rememberMe)
    {   
        // Check if user has already logged in. If so, do not allow to log in 
        // twice.
        if ($this->authService->getIdentity()!=null) {
          //throw new \Exception('Already logged in');
        }

        // Authenticate with login/password.
        $authAdapter = $this->authService->getAdapter();
        $authAdapter->setUsername($email);
        $authAdapter->setPassword($password);
        $result = $this->authService->authenticate();

        // If user wants to "remember him", we will make session to expire in 
        // one month. By default session expires in 1 hour (as specified in our 
        // config/global.php file).
        if ($result->getCode()==Result::SUCCESS && $rememberMe) {
            // Session cookie will expire in 1 month (30 days).
            $this->sessionManager->rememberMe(60*60*24*30);
        }

        return $result;
    }



     /**
         * This is a simple access control filter. It is able to restrict unauthorized
         * users to visit certain pages.
         * 
         * This method uses the 'access_filter' key in the config file and determines
         * whenther the current visitor is allowed to access the given controller action
         * or not. It returns true if allowed; otherwise false.
         */
        public function filterAccess($controllerName, $actionName)
        {
            // Determine mode - 'restrictive' (default) or 'permissive'. In restrictive
            // mode all controller actions must be explicitly listed under the 'access_filter'
            // config key, and access is denied to any not listed action for unauthorized users. 
            // In permissive mode, if an action is not listed under the 'access_filter' key, 
            // access to it is permitted to anyone (even for not logged in users.
            // Restrictive mode is more secure and recommended to use.
            $mode = isset($this->config['options']['mode'])?$this->config['options']['mode']:'restrictive';
            if ($mode!='restrictive' && $mode!='permissive')
                throw new \Exception('Invalid access filter mode (expected either restrictive or permissive mode');

            if (isset($this->config['controllers'][$controllerName])) {
                $items = $this->config['controllers'][$controllerName];
                foreach ($items as $item) {
                    $actionList = $item['actions'];
                    $allow = $item['allow'];
                    if (is_array($actionList) && in_array($actionName, $actionList) ||
                        $actionList=='*') {
                        if ($allow=='*')
                            return true; // Anyone is allowed to see the page.
                        else if ($allow=='@' && $this->authService->hasIdentity()) {
                            return true; // Only authenticated user is allowed to see the page.
                        } else {                    
                            return false; // Access denied.
                        }
                    }
                }            
            }

            // In restrictive mode, we forbid access for unauthorized users to 
    any 
            // action not listed under 'access_filter' key (for security 
    reasons).
            if ($mode=='restrictive' && !$this->authService->hasIdentity())
                return false;

            // Permit access to this page.
            return true;
        }
```

take for example the url registration action in the index controller is set to /application/registration, if l use this url in the browser it doesnt redirect me to the login page , it just serves the page.

What could be wrong with my access filtering?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure "filterAccess" function works well?

Answer (score 0):

Well your "filterAccess" and "onDispatch" methods works well. Seems problem is authService's "hasIdentity" method. You can't retrieve correct result from this method.

Also i think you should check for access on "onRoute" event. It seems too late on controller's "ondispatch" event. Checkout "AuthorizationMiddleware" listener on [zf3 docs](https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-mvc/cookbook/middleware-in-listeners/)

Comment: Thank you, will have a look at that